# Carga bien con el servidor de laravel pero no carga con xampp

Tags: laravel-5, xampp

Estoy haciendo unas rutas en Laravel cuando cargo estas rutas con el servidor de Laravel me funciona bien `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products`

Me responde el `return` del controlador que es 'buenas noches'

la ruta es

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
```

y la vista:

```
Route::get('/' , function(){

    return view('app');
});
```

Controlador:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return 'buenas noches';
    } 

 }
```

En app esta :

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        @yield('content')
        <a href="{{ route('products.index') }}">info</a>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
    </body>
```

pero cuando lo utilizo con xampp :

```
http://home.pro/laravel/tienda1/public/products
```

Me muestra:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: no entiendo si ya tienes un resource controller para que ocupas declarar una ruta por separado con GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento un par de cosas respecto a tu código.

1. Si ya tienes un resource controller, que va a controlar la petición de mostrar esa vista en específico a través del método index; lo único que deberías tener en tu código es:

El el archivo routes.js

```
Route::resource('/products', 'ProductoController');
```

En tu controlador, donde hola es el nombre de la vista pero tu puedes ponerle el que quieras

```
public function index() 
    {
        return view('hola');
    }
```

Y finalmente la URL que deberías trabajar en tu XAMPP es la siguiente

> http://localhost/pruebas/public/products

A menos que hayas configurado un servidor especifico, tu URL se debe componer de:

1. localhost => Pues apuntas a un recurso de tu propia PC
2. pruebas => este es el nombre del proyecto completo tu sustituyelo por el que le pusiste al tuyo
3. public => ahi esta el frontend controller entonces procesa las peticiones que llegan al Framework
4. products => es la URL que declaré como punto de acceso en mi archivo routes.php

**LO QUE NO VEO NECESARIO**

Salvo que tu nos expliques que uso le das, el siguiente fragmento de código lo veo de mas; es decir no debería ir

```
Route::get('/' , function(){

    return view('app');
});
```

**UNA ALTERNATIVA MAS**

Si por alguna razón esa vista que intentas devolver no tiene contenido dinámico, es decir que interactue con BD puedes evitar la parte del controller y usar la utilidad que esta desde Laravel 5.6; del modo siguiente

```
Route::view('/productos','hola');
```

> Donde primero colocas la URL que debe responder y segundo el nombre de
>   la vista que vas a invocar; pero OJO solo es para vistas de contenido
>   estático

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta es que el servidor de laravel empieza a correr desde la carpeta public, lo cual al tratar de aceder a la raiz, lo hace en `public/` y en xampp, la raiz en `htdocs` la solucion es crear un dominio local que apunte a `http://home.pro/laravel/tienda1/public/`

1. Dirigete al archivo `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host`
2. Agrega tu host al final del archivo asi `127.0.0.1       tienda1.com`
3. Guarda el archivo, necesitaras permiso de administrador. te recomiendo editarlo con notepad++
4. Ahora dirigete a archivo `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`
5. Edita el archivo y diriges tu host a tu carpeta del proyecto

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin admin@tienda1.com
       DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\tienda1\public"
       ServerName tienda1.com
       ErrorLog "logs/tienda1.com-error.log"
       CustomLog "logs/tienda1.com-access.log" common
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

con esto deberia funcionar